# Using VBA to sort by multiple column headers

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am looking to sort columns by header names since the column where the header is may change using VBA. I found the below code but couldnt figure out how to make it sort by more than one field. Basically i am looking to have this filter by KEY, Status, Enrolled on, Completed on in that order.

```
Dim sortAdd As String
Dim sortRange As Range

'Find which column "KEY" appears in
On Error GoTo err_chk
Rows("1:1").Find(What:="KEY", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
On Error GoTo 0
sortAdd = ActiveCell.Address(0, 0)

'Set sort range by using current region
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort _
    key1:=Range(sortAdd), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    
Exit Sub
  'Error handling
err_chk:
If Err.Number = 91 Then
    MsgBox "No header row with title of KEY", vbOKOnly, "ERROR!"
Else
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End If
```

Recorded macro seemed to work but not really ideal.

```
Range("Deduped[[#Headers],[Key]]").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Deduped").ListObjects("Deduped").sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Deduped").ListObjects("Deduped").sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("Deduped[Key]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Deduped").ListObjects("Deduped").sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("Deduped[HR Status]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Deduped").ListObjects("Deduped").sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("Deduped[Enrolled on Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Deduped").ListObjects("Deduped").sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("Deduped[Completion Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
    :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Deduped").ListObjects("Deduped").sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sort On Multiple Columns

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortOnMultipleColumns()
    
    Dim SortHeaders As Variant
    SortHeaders = Array("KEY", "Status", "Enrolled on", "Completed")
    Dim SortOrders As Variant
    SortOrders = Array(xlAscending, xlAscending, xlAscending, xlAscending)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim shrg As Range: Set shrg = srg.Rows(1)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ColumnIndex As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = LBound(SortHeaders) To UBound(SortHeaders)
        ColumnIndex = Application.Match(SortHeaders(n), shrg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(ColumnIndex) Then
            srg.Sort srg.Columns(ColumnIndex), SortOrders(n), , , , , , xlYes
        Else
            MsgBox "Could not find the header '" & SortHeaders(n) & "'.", _
                vbCritical
        End If
    Next n
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this is great but it seems to give different results than when i manually do customer sort. any idea why?

Comment: ended up using a recorded macro that seems to do the job.

Comment: Could you share, please, so I can figure out what is wrong with this solution?

Comment: Ive updated my question with the recorded VBA code. Honestly im not sure how the different sort methods work but yours did sort each column but individually instead of as a custome sort.

Comment: Next time you need to tell us that your dealing with an Excel (structured) table and share the specifics e.g. the correct names of the workbook, worksheets, tables, and table headers. As you can see for yourself, it's a totally different code.

Comment: Sorry i did tag the question with "Excel" and i did give the names of the headers. but really that doesnt matter as i can update that to match what it have. The code is totaly different because its a recorded macro vs manually written. Do you know what the manually written VBA would look like?